# Auto focus div tag using jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add autofocus for my div tag. for that I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("div_error").focus();
            });

    </script >
```

but this does not focus to my div tag. it loads page as normal.

```
 <div  id="div_error">some text</div>
```

what did I miss

Comment: your selector is wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set focus on DIV tag, set a `tabindex` attribute:

```
<div  id="div_error" tabindex="-1">some text</div>
```

BTW, your selector is wrong, forgot to prefix it with '#':

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#div_error").focus();
            });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hTs5Y/)

Comment: why do we need tabindex="-1" ?

Comment: @Lahiruzz because without it, by default a DIV element is not focusable. You could wish for styling to use CSS `outline:0` for this DIV element

Comment: Now , I'm using Jquery mobile, now this does not work. do you know any reason for that?